# Is the final sentence grammatical? What is its meaning?

Tags: grammaticality, syntax, subject-auxiliary-inversion

Is the final sentence grammatical? What is its meaning?

> In reply to the first question, some said that to know the right time for every action, one must draw up in advance, a table of days, months and years, and must live strictly according to it. Only thus, said they, could everything be done at its proper time. **Only thus, said they, could everything be done at its proper time.**

Source: [“Three Questions” By Leo Tolstoy](https://gohighbrow.com/three-questions/)

Comment: I have edited the question to provide essential context.

Comment: But you should still explain exactly what it is about the sentence that confuses you. I see at least two possible concerns.

Comment: Only thus said they meaning?

Comment: **Could everything be done at its proper time** is it a question?

Comment: It's *slightly* unusual / poetic word sequencing (especially ***said they***, which would normally go the other way round). The *meaning* is more clearly expressed by *They said that only thus* [only by doing that - drawing up the table and living by it] *would it be possible to ensure that everything was done at the appropriate time*.

Comment: *...everything* about the phrasing is a bit "literary", so it wouldn't normally occur in a *conversational* context. But if it *did*, those first five words would normally be replaced by ***They said that only thus** [could everything be done...]*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Could everything be done at its proper time" -- is it a question?

No, it's not a question. You were right in noticing that the auxiliary verb **could** is placed before the subject **everything**. So as a standalone sentence, it would be a question. Questions have inverted subject-auxiliary order: "everything [SUBJECT] could [AUXILIARY] be done" - "could [AUXILIARY] everything [SUBJECT] be done?"

However, in your example it's not a question. Why? Because of the phrase **only thus**, which is a restrictive phrase. You see, after negative and restrictive phrases we can do [subject-auxiliary inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93auxiliary_inversion). This is done to provide emphasis. Hence, it's often done in literature.

Negative phrase "never":

> I will **never** jump into the sea.
> **Never** will I jump into the sea. (inversion: "will I jump into the sea" looks like a question, but it's not)

Restrictive phrase "Only for a million dollars":

> I will jump into the sea only for a million dollars.
> Only for a million dollars will I jump into the sea. (inversion: "I will jump" -> "will I jump")

I've added the tag "subject-auxiliary inversion" to your question, you can look up questions related to this topic.

Comment: I will jump..=will i jump...(bothe have same sense but only difference is the second one is emphatic)am i right?

Comment: @Asu - yes, the second is more emphatic and "literature-like"